# IDE hard drive and a SATA Dock

Tags: sata, adapter, pata, docking-station

I bought a very nice SATA dock for my computer, plug and play and you just plug the drive into the dock and you can access the data.

I have since then found an IDE drive i wish to access, but cant figure out how to do it, as i would guess i need, one cable converting IDE to SATA and one cable to plug it into a SATA power connection.

Dock = http://tiny.cc/dc5ie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too have one of those SATA docks, and it's awesome. Until someone brings you an IDE drive and needs their precious photos and music off it.

I got this great little USB dongle that does SATA and IDE, it comes with a power adapter as well. It might not be the best brand name but when I've had to use mine it works great.

[Inland USB to IDE/SATA on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001JQMEBM)

Answer (score 1):

I purchased an IDE<->SATA adapter a while back so I could install a SATA drive in a computer, but it didn't even work.

Even if you can find an IDE->SATA adapter that works, using it with your SATA dock probably still wouldn't work very well, because the positioning of the interface connectors would cause the drive to lean to one side.  This would exert a lot of stress on the connectors, breaking the dock, the adapter, the drive, or some combination of the three.

I think your best bet is to buy a cheap IDE-to USB cable or an IDE-to-USB enclosure for $15.  If you get the enclosure, you have the additional option of leaving the outer casing off, making it almost as convenient as the SATA dock.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't as simple as just a cable to convert from IDE to SATA.  You will need a conversion unit which has actual circuitry.  Go on amazon and search for IDE to SATA converter.